# Global solutions for a system with input

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Denote the real line by $\mathcal{R}$ and the non-negative real line by $\mathcal{R}^+$. Consider given functions $f:\mathcal{R}^n\times\mathcal{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathcal{R}^n$ and $u:\mathcal{R}^+\longrightarrow\mathcal{R}^m$. We then have the ODE system with input $u$:
$$x'(t)=f(x(t),u(t)),$$
for all $t\in\mathcal{R}^+$. The solutions to this system are functions $x:\mathcal{R}^+\longrightarrow\mathcal{R}^n$ which are differentiable an satisfy the systems equation globally.

**My question:** Under which conditions on the function $f$ and the input $u$ can I claim that there exists at least a solution $x$ on all $\mathcal{R}^+$?

Comment: The problem is that such solution needs not to be global. For example, with no input: x'=x^2 and x(0)=1 has solution 1/(1-t) that escapes to infinity in finite time.

Comment: Your question is basically whether a given nonlinear system (with inputs) is stable, right? Then Input-to-State stability (ISS) should give conditions that guarantee there exists a solution.